# Cover html-table during content fetching

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have VueJS component which loads data and renders it on the page ( html-tag) with pagination. The table height is unpredictable. Sometime it contain only a few rows, sometime there are multi-line content within single row.

When I click the pagination button, the data refreshes and it takes some time. So, now I just hide the whole  table during data fetching and show "loading..." animation, but I don't like this solution due to the page content jumping. I would prefer to show `<div>` over the table, with something like `opacity: 0.5`, but I am not sure it is possible because unclear the tables`s height value.

Have anybody an idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: How about a Bootstrap Modal showing loading animation?

Comment: Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.